# $ \lim_{x \to 0} a^x = 1 $ using the definition

Tags: calculus

Given $a > 1$, define $ f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $ x \in \mathbb{Q}$ we have $ f(x) = a^x$ . Prove that $ \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 1$

---

I'm having issues to find my delta. I think we need to use $ \log_a$ of something in function of $ \epsilon$ but I couldn't find it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick $\varepsilon>0$ and re-write it as $\varepsilon=e^{\alpha}-1$. Want to find a $\delta$ such that $|a^{x}-1|<\varepsilon$ for $0<|x-0|<\delta$.
$|a^{x}-1|<e^{\alpha}-1$

$|a^{x}|=a^{x}<e^{\alpha}$

$x\log(a)<\alpha$

so for $|x-0|<\frac{\alpha}{\log(a)}$ it folows that $|a^{x}-1|<\varepsilon$

Answer (score 2):

Actually in this case the limit does not exist. For limit $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ to exist, it is absolutely necessary that $f(x)$ be defined in a certain neighborhood of $0$ (i.e. any open interval containing $0$) except possibly at $x = 0$. Since your definition of $f$ says that it is defined only for rational $x$, then we have a problem taking limits.

Perhaps you can do something like this. You want to let $x \to 0$ through rational values only so it makes sense to put $ x = 1/n$ ($n$ being an integer) and then $n \to \infty$. In that case we can say that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a^{1/n} = 1$. The negative values of $x$ can be also be handled and we can write $\lim_{n \to -\infty}a^{1/n} = 1$.